# How to alert value on keypress event?

Tags: jquery, window, chat

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = [];   
    $(document).on('click', '.msg_head', function() {   
        var chatbox = $(this).parents().attr("rel") ;
        $('[rel="'+chatbox+'"] .msg_wrap').slideToggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.close', function() {  
        var chatbox = $(this).parents().parents().attr("rel") ;
        $('[rel="'+chatbox+'"]').hide();
        arr.splice($.inArray(chatbox, arr), 1);
        displayChatBox();
        return false;
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#sidebar-user-box', function() {
        var userID = $(this).attr("class");
        var username = $(this).children().text() ;
        if ($.inArray(userID, arr) != -1)
        {
            arr.splice($.inArray(userID, arr), 1);
        }
        arr.unshift(userID);
        chatPopup = '<div class="msg_box" style="right:270px;z-index: 1000;" id="'+userID+'" rel="'+ userID+'">'+
                    '<div class="msg_head">'+username +
                    '<div class="close">x</div> </div>'+
                    '<div class="msg_wrap"> <div class="msg_body"><div class="msg_push"></div></div>'+
                    '<div class="msg_footer"><textarea class="msg_input" rows="4" placeholder="Type a message..." style="padding: 8px;" id="'+userID+'"></textarea></div>'+
                    '<button type="submit" name="submit" id="'+userID+'" class="send_rec"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>    </div>  </div>' ;                   

        $("body").append(chatPopup);
        displayChatBox();
    });
    $(document).on('keypress', 'textarea' , function(e) {       
        if (e.keyCode == 13 ) {         
            var msg = $(this).val();        
            $(this).val('');
            if(msg.trim().length != 0){             
                var chatbox = $(this).parents().parents().parents().attr("rel") ;
                $('<div class="msg-right">'+msg+'</div>').insertBefore('[rel="'+chatbox+'"] .msg_push');
                $('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);
            }
        }
    });
    function displayChatBox(){ 
        i = 270 ;
        j = 260;
        $.each( arr, function( index, value ) {  
            if(index < 4){
                $('[rel="'+value+'"]').css("right",i);
                $('[rel="'+value+'"]').show();
                i = i+j;             
            }
            else{
                $('[rel="'+value+'"]').hide();
            }
        });     
    }
    $(document).on("keypress", "button",function(){
        friend_id = this.id;
        alert(friend_id);
    });
});
```

In this code I have create a chatbox window. Now, what happen when I use the following code as mention below it alert value.

```
$(document).on("keypress", "textarea",function(){
        friend_id = this.id;
        alert(friend_id);
    });
```

but when I using

```
$(document).on("keypress", "button",function(){
        friend_id = this.id;
        alert(friend_id);
    });
```

nothing will happen when I use `keypress` over button I don't know why? What is the problem with `button`? So, How can I get value in alert box when `keypress` on button? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Do you want to get id of element?

Comment: keypress on a button? is that even possible. looks like you want click instead of keypress

Comment: yes, I want get id inside the `button` @GufranHasan

Comment: @MattJameson I guess technically it could work if focus was set on the button and then activated with a keypress (like space or enter). But normally you use the `click` event on buttons. Not the keypress event.

Comment: try this `friend_id = $(this).attr('id');`

Comment: I have tried `friend_id = $(this).attr('id');` but still not working @GufranHasan

Comment: @Rudra What are you trying to do? A `keypress` event is a key on the keyboard. Not a mouse click. And it will only trigger on buttons if the focus is set on the button first.

Comment: ok, @icecub I want when I write on somthing on `textarea` and when I press enter it will alert `userID` as well as `textarea` value.

Comment: @Rudra looks like youve already got an event for that in your code?

Comment: Now that makes a lot more sense. Try adding this code: `$('textarea').on("keypress", function (e) { if(e.which === 13){ friend_id = this.id; alert(friend_id); } });` instead of your `$(document).on...`

Comment: Thank you @icecub. you save my day.

Comment: @Rudra You're welcome. Keep this in mind for when you ask a question next time. Explain what it is that you want to achieve. Your approach might be wrong and you'll only receive answers that won't help you. When you explain what you want, we're able to tell you that and actually give you an answer that does help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After gaining more information from OP in the comments, it became clear that he wants to alert the `userID` and the textarea value when the Enter key is pressed inside the textarea. One approach to achieve this would be:

```
// Event handler on textareas
$('textarea').on("keypress", function (e) {

    // Detect Enter key pressed
    if(e.which === 13){

        // Get the userID
        let friend_id = this.id;

        // Get the textarea value
        let txt_val = this.value;

        // Alert the data
        alert('userID: '+friend_id+' Textarea Value: '+txt_val);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the click event. Your code DOES work for a keypress event.

```js
$(document).on("click", "button",function(){
        friend_id = this.id;
        alert(friend_id);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnTest">Test</button>
```

Comment: A `click` event may be more appropriate here, but a `button` does still respond to a `keypress` event.

Comment: Interesting, never used it. Edited

Comment: I suggest you read the last comments. OP made it more clear what he actually wants. Feel free to use my comment to improve your answer.